# Can I build a ML model with independent variables containing (time series+ categorical +numeric) and a classifier dependent variable (0,1)

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification

Let's say I have with me data containing 
salary, 
job profile, 
work experience, 
number of people in household, 
other demographic etc ..
of multiple persons who visited my car dealership and I also have the data if he/she has bought a car from me or not.

I can leverage this dataset to predict if a new customer coming in is likely to buy a car or not. And let's say currently I am doing it using xgboost.

NOW, I have got additional data but it is a time series data of the monthly expenditure the person makes. Say I get the data for my training data too. Now I want to build a model which uses this time series data and the old demographics data(+ salary, age etc) to get to know if a customer is likely to buy or not.

Note: In the second part I have time series data of the monthly expenditure only. The other variables are at a point in time. For example I do not have the time series for Salary or Age.

Note2: I also have categorical variables like job profile which I would like to use in the model. But for this I do not know if the person has been in the same job profile or he has changed over from some other job profile.

Comment: Yes, you need something like RNN + NN architecture.

Comment: I agree with @BillChen's comment, I would add that if you wanted to do some preliminary approaches you could extract statistics from the time series data (e.g. mean, mode, median, variance, etc) and use those as additional features. That might be a place to start before trying something more complicated to setup like an RNN.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the answers. The feature extraction part is fairly straight forward. I was quite interested in the RNN. A friend suggested that I could use LSTM on just the expenditure(time series variable) and get the probability classifiers accordingly. Then use this result as another feature on the existing xgboost model. So essentially I am using LSTM to get a feature to be added in the existing model. Will it work? And has anyone tried it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most of the data are specific to the person; except expenditure time series, so it is better to bring time series data at person level. This can be done by feature engineering like:

1. As @cmxu suggested take various statistical measures. It will be even more beneficial to take these statistical measures at different time intervals like say mean at last 2 days, 5 days, 7 days, 15 days, 30 day, 90 days, 180 days etc.
2. Create mixed features like:
   a) ratio of salary vs expenditure statistical summery created in point 1 (choose appropriate interval) 
   b) salary per person household or avg monthly expenditure per household. etc.

   With similar ideas you can easily create 100s or 1000s of features with your data and then feed all this data to XGBoost (which is easy to train and debug) or NN (more complicated to train).